# Issues Creating a Widget with Query settings using devOps rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am having troubles identifying the cause of my problem. I am trying to use the Create Widget Rest API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/widgets/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

The issue i am facing, is when i try to add the settings parameters, to reference the Query for the specific Widget, i get an error.

```
{'$id': '1',
 'innerException': None,
 'message': 'Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: widget',
 'typeName': 'System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib',
 'typeKey': 'ArgumentNullException',
 'errorCode': 0,
 'eventId': 0
}
```

This is the payload im using for the POST Create Widget API

```
payload = {
  "name": "Open Issues",
  "position": {
      "row": 2, 
      "column": 6
  },
  "size": {
      "rowSpan": 1, 
      "columnSpan": 1
  },
  "settings": {
      "defaultBackgroundColor":"#51399f",
      "queryId":"2d5d4371-bb0d-4984-b277-f71eca948d34",
      "queryName":"Open Issues",
      "colorRules":[{
          "isEnabled":True,
          "backgroundColor":"#339947",
          "thresholdCount":0,
          "operator":"<="}],
      "lastArtifactName": "Open Issues"
  },
  "settingsVersion": {    
      "major": 1,    
      "minor": 0,    
      "patch": 0 
  },
  "contributionId": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.Microsoft.VisualStudioOnline.Dashboards.QueryScalarWidget"
}
```

If i set "settings": "null", it creates the widget without an issue (but missing the query reference).

I have used the Get Widgets, to ensure that im using the correct format, but still getting an error.With the Get Widget call i get the following format (which is exactly what i am using):

```
{
    "id": "8d8697f3-a2db-4df8-8c15-26374c1191d9",
    "eTag": "14",
    "name": "Open Issues",
    "position": {
        "row": 2,
        "column": 6
    },
    "size": {
        "rowSpan": 1,
        "columnSpan": 1
    },
    "settings": {
        "defaultBackgroundColor": "#51399f",
        "queryId": "f525ec14-3d75-4798-b014-9513c79fd0aa",
        "queryName": "Open Issues",
        "colorRules": [
            {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "backgroundColor": "#339947",
                "thresholdCount": 0,
                "operator": "<="
            }
        ],
        "lastArtifactName": "Open Issues"
    },
    "settingsVersion": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 0,
        "patch": 0
    }
}
```

Has anyone else faced this issue, or has anyone managed to get this to work?

Any help will be very welcome :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the same request body.

The cause of the issue is that the format of the settings field has issue.

The value of the settings field is passed as a whole string rather than as an object.

To solve this issue, you can change to use the following Request body:

```
{
  "name": "Open Issues",
  "position": {
      "row": 2, 
      "column": 6
  },
  "size": {
      "rowSpan": 1, 
      "columnSpan": 1
  },
    "settings": "{\"defaultBackgroundColor\":\"#51399f\",\"queryId\":\"2d5d4371-bb0d-4984-b277-f71eca948d34\",\"queryName\":\"Open Issues\",\"colorRules\":[{\"isEnabled\":true,\"backgroundColor\":\"#339947\",\"thresholdCount\":0,\"operator\":\"<=\"}],\"lastArtifactName\":\"Open Issues\"}",

  "settingsVersion": {    
      "major": 1,    
      "minor": 0,    
      "patch": 0 
  },
  "contributionId": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.Microsoft.VisualStudioOnline.Dashboards.QueryScalarWidget"
}
```